# Getting search_path to work with Npgsql

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

What is the appropriate way to set the `search_path` for a particular user on either the entire database or just a schema in PostgreSQL in order for it to work via **Npgsql**?

Let's take my user `reader` for example.

I've tried setting `reader's` search_path in the database itself via

```
alter default privileges in schema auth grant select on tables to reader;
```

I've tried setting it in the `postgresql.conf` file (`search_path = 'auth'`).

I've tried setting it in my `web.config` file in the `connectionString` node (`...;searchpath=auth;...`).

None of these appear to work. When I attempt to use my connection to access a table called `users`, I get the error

```
ERROR: 42P01: relation "users" does not exist
```

If I specify the schema (`e.g.  "select * from auth.users ..."`) then it'll work.

(Actually at this point I get the error `ERROR: 42501: permission denied for schema auth1` which is the next issue I'll have to address, but the search_path issue appears to be resolved).

So what do I need to do to set the search_path for a particular user when using **Npgsql**?

Note: I'm using dapper dot net and can make queries successfully with my super user `postgres`.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting IIS Express and PostgreSQL didn't do anything but after rebooting my machine I no longer need to supply the schema, though I'm not sure which of the three methods actually did the trick. Just fyi for anyone who might come across this.